# Fechar conexão PDO

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, pdo

Já trabalhei com outras linguagens antes de trabalhar com PHP e em algumas o framework quando você abria uma conexão com o banco era bom finalizar a mesma, no PDO pelo que percebi não existe uma função na classe PDO que feche essa conexão. Existe alguma forma no PDO de *fechar a conexão* com o banco?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Olha, mais simples impossível:

```
$pdo = null;
```

claro que isto não se faz necessário pois a conexão é fechada automaticamente após a execução do script

Answer (score 0):

Apesar de não ter muita relação coma dúvida original, vale a pena comentar.

Como você disse ter visto num framework, certeza quase absoluta (vai que...) de que este era Orientado a Objetos e nesses casos, uma implementação da PDO precisa ter a propriedade em que a instância do objeto PDO em si destruída para que a lógica de conexão funcione por conectar apenas uma única vez.

A grosso modo é mais ou menos assim:

```
abstract class Driver {

    protected $conn;

    public function getConnection() {

        if( $this -> conn === NULL ) {

             $this -> connect();
        }

        return $this -> conn;
    }

    abstract public function connect();

    abstract public function disconnect();
}

class PDO extends Driver {

    public function connect() {

        $this -> conn = new PDO( /** .. */ );
    }

    public function disconnect() {

        $this -> conn = NULL;
    }

}
```

> Nota: Não foi levado em consideração *namespaces*, interfaces ou mesmo paradigmas de Orientação a Objetos para simplificar ao máximo.

Assim, dado o fluxo da Requisição vertical e crescente, um objeto de conexão definido, digamos, num Application Controller poderá ser usado num Action Controller ou numa Model sem risco de perda de dados.

E no caso da PDO pelo menos é bem importante haja vista que parte das operações são realizadas na PDO e parte na PDOStatement e qualquer re-conexão indevida entre uma etapa e outra pode, por exemplo, gerar um erro de query vazia.