# Como fechar uma conexão com o banco de dados usando PDO?

Tags: php, pdo, conexão

Eu sou novo na área de desenvolvimento PHP e meu app usa um método para abrir uma conexão com o banco de dados em **MySQL**, estou querendo atualizar e exibir os registros.

Preciso usar algum método para fechar a conexão, tipo: `function close()`?

```
public function ($)
    {
        $sql  = "";
        try
        {
            $stmt = connectionDB::prepare($sql);
            if($stmt->execute())
            {
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            echo "Err ->" . $e->getMessage();
        }

        finally{
             try {
                 $stmt = connectionDB::close();
             }
        }
}
```

### Minha classe:

```
class ClassDao extends Dao {

    public function insert($registro)
    {
        $sql  = "INSERT INTO table () VALUES ()";
        try
        {
            $stmt = connectionDB::prepare($sql);
            if($stmt->execute())
            {
                echo "INSERT!!";
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            echo "Err ->" . $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

    public function update($registro)
    {
        $sql  = "UPDATE table SET var = :var, WHERE var = :var";
        try
        {
            $stmt = connectionDB::prepare($sql);
            if($stmt->execute()){
                echo "UPDATE!!";
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            echo "Err ->" . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function findAll()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
        try
        {
            $stmt = connectionDB::prepare($sql);
            if($stmt->execute()){
                return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,'table');
            }
            else {
                return new Class();
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            echo "Err ->" . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function createObject($r)
    {
        try{
            $var= new Class($r['var1'], $r['var2']);
            return $var;
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            echo "Err ->" . $e->getMessage();   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Fechar conexão PDO](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16288/91) e [Conexões e gerenciamento](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30923/91)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$pdo = null;
```

Você pode usar como no exemplo acima mais não é de uso obrigatório pois a conexão é fechada automaticamente após a execução do script.